# Mocking ScrapySharp response for unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, scrapysharp

I'm using ScrapySharp in my clean architecture solution and I need to mock a Scraping service response in my unit tests so that the unit test is self contained and not actually hitting any external server.

I've looked at using Moq but don't see a way to return a new ScrapySharp WebPage for my code then to use during the unit test.

I have an interface for my service in my infrastructure project:

```
public interface IScrapeService
{
    WebPage NavigateToPage(Uri url, HttpVerb verb = HttpVerb.Get, string data = "", string contentType = null);
}
```

I then would have my real world implementation of this service that would get injected into the class which uses the service.  My unit test would use a mocked implementation of the service that would get injected during my test.

Has anybody attempted anything like this or can help me if I'm not thinking about this properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question here is: Why do you need to expose ScrapySharp's response as output value of your method? May be it is a better to return some custom model which will contain only required information from ScrapySharp's response. Custom model will give one more advantage - all clients of your IScrapeService interface will not need to have explicit reference to ScrapySharp. And, of course, it will give you better abilities for testing of this interface.

Comment: Thanks Michael.  It's a good question and making me think more about what is returned.

My custom model is introduced later in the code workflow but I'll have a look and see if the code can be refactored to maybe return the html string.  The issue is there are forms that are manipulated and posted to get data back from the website which are then used to populate my custom models.  So the ScrapeService is returning the page in order to do this.  Hopefully I can refactor to use html and the problem goes away.  Cheers for the nudge!

Comment: In the end, I got rid of ScrapySharp and just used HttpClient.  I was then able to use MockHTTP from Richard Szalay.  I have my live and mock services set up and all looking good.  Thanks again Michael for the steer!